# Reverse order of clips when importing from card or camera in Final Cut Pro X?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, workflow

When I'm doing to-camera commentary in my studio, a regular part of my workflow is to record some footage on my DSLR and then import it immediately into Final Cut Pro X. I'll often need another take (or ten) before I've finished so it's really annoying that when FCPX fetches the files it does it in the order they were shot, so the file I want is always the last to appear.

[image: Import screen]

Is there any way to make Final Cut Pro X fetch the most recently recorded file *first* instead?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. In my experience the contents isn't loaded in any particular order, so setting the order to ascending content created date doesn't actually change the order the files are loaded. You can still try setting the date order to ascending if you wish: click the [image] button on the status bar then click the ‘content created’ header to sort ascending.

Answer (score 0):

Try the other answer first. Just import it, and press the organize button.

Otherwise,

From looking at your picture (book by it's cover analysis):

1. Where do you get the file name? Ex. PQ9A3..(confusing to ordering program?) (How does the computer supposed to know if it is (0, 1, 2, 3, and 4?)
2. Try to rename a few of your clips to (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) and see what happens. If the ordering works... you have problems with your filename system.

The computer understands this order for File Explorer:

[image]

See if it works on Mac. I usually use Windows, but the concepts should be very similar.